# ListPlot with labels that appear when the pointer goes over the points

Tags: plotting

I would like to generate a `ListPlot` with labels that appear when the pointer goes over the individual points.
Specifically, I have a table of dimensions `{100,3}` and I want to use the first two columns for the plot and the third for the label.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Maybe something like: `ListPlot[Tooltip@Prime[Range[25]], Filling -> Axis]`. Is that what you try to do?

Comment: Thanks! It is almost what I want. Say that I have a table `tab` of dimensions `{100,3}` and I want to use the first two columns for the plot and the third for the label. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Please update your question with the additional information you supplied in your comment. It makes the question quite different than as originally posted.

Comment: Also have a look at `BubbleChart`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on update question: It seems that `ListPlot` cannot handle `Tooltip` "directly", so I used a `Table` to add a `Tooltip` to each point.

I use the following random data:

```
data = Append[#, RandomChoice[{"label1", "label2", "label3"}]] & /@ 
RandomInteger[100, {10, 2}] 

(*{{80, 14, "label1"}, {98, 70, "label1"}, {66, 86, "label3"}, {43, 90, 
"label2"}, {82, 29, "label2"}, {65, 91, "label1"}, {68, 59, 
 "label3"}, {9, 56, "label1"}, {17, 50, "label2"}, {79, 99, 
 "label3"}}*)
```

And then plot:

```
ListPlot[Table[Tooltip[data[[i, 1 ;; 2]], data[[i, 3]]], {i, Length@data}]]
```

[image: pointless animation added]

Is this what you wanted?

**EDIT**

Based on Mr.Wizard's comment (see below), we can also concisely write:

```
ListPlot[Tooltip[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ data]
```

Comment: added pictures... ;)

Comment: @cormullion: thanks! that's something I never really understood on my mac...

Comment: You can use QuickTimePlayer to record the screen, then import the file and export it to animated GIF. Of course, embedded movies would be easier...

Comment: ah thanks, I'll try that! (for next time)

Comment: Good answer.  However, you should read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121), and then understand: `ListPlot[Tooltip[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ data]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: thanks for that input, it didn't occur to me the moment I wrote the answer! I will add it to the answer for completness

Comment: This is great!  Now is there a way to export this so others without Mathematica can see it?